# How to create horizontal lists using display:inline?

Tags: css, list, inline

I'm trying to create a horizontally displayed list of services, however `display: inline` isn't working. How do I display the `li`'s horizontally?

```
#services {
    border-top: 1px solid #202020;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#services p span {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    font-size: 112.5%;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#services ul {
    width: 160px;
}

#services ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#services ul li h2 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

<div id="services">
    <p><span>Services</span></p>
    <ul>
    <li><h2>HEADING</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
    <li><h2>HEADING</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
    <li><h2>HEADING</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
    <li><h2>HEADING</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="next">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/next.png" alt="Click for more information" /></a>
    </div><!-- end next -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not showing horizontally, or arranging themselves 'inline' with any noticeable difference due to the `ul` being too wide to allow more than one `li` to show in that horizontal space.

the issue is here

```
#services ul {
    width: 160px;
}
```

remove this width restriction to allow more than one li to fit horizontally.

Furthermore, to achieve the effect I believe you are looking for, try settings a set width for the list items and and settings the display to `inline-block` rather than inline. This will create the horizontal blocks that I believe you are attempting to achieve.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xPCBK/1/

The css you need to change:

```
#services ul {
    width: 160px;
}

#services ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Change this to

```
#services ul {
}
#services ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
}
```

Comment: I put the width restriction there because I want each individual `li` to be 160px. Removing that function, however, did not allow the `li`s to be displayed horizontally. Is there a better way to achieve horizontal `li`'s with a width of 160px?

Comment: You set the width of the `ul` to 160px, this is the whole list width rather than the individual list items (`li`). See my example.

Comment: No worries :) remember to accept the answer if this solved your issue ;)